# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 4, col 0 from CursorWindow

Tags: java, android, android-cursor

While trying to read data from database, I'm getting this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 4, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

The number of rows in the cursor are 24, the code is giving exception at row number 22. The code I use is the following:

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
            SomeData someData = new SomeData();
            someData.setQuestion(c.getString(0)); //Exception is coming in this line
            someData.setOption1(c.getString(1));
            someData.setOption2(c.getString(2));
            someData.setOption3(c.getString(3));
            someData.setOption4(c.getString(4));
            someData.setAnswer(c.getString(5));
            outMap.put(c.getString(6), someData );
 }
```

The column value(string) for 22nd row record is 699059 characters long. I suspect that the error is a result of large String value.

Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: I believe the limit is 2MB. [Check this SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432556/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-couldnt-read-row-0-col-0-from-cursorw)

Comment: I have just encountered the same problem, but with fetching int value. [Check this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68344) and see if your problem happens in same conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to current implementation **config_cursorWindowSize** support maximum of 2 MB size.If row size exceeds then it will throw error.