# CursorWindow: Window is full

Tags: java, android, listview, android-sqlite, android-camera-intent

I'm new and after days, maybe I found that I have this issue, I have a very big data in a big listView

`W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1432389 bytes, free space 750700 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes`

`E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 64 columns.`

`W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x420aeda0)
03-03 15:50:00.162 16239-16239/id.co.bumisentosa.yantek E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`

I have read some same issue
[android java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432556/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-couldnt-read-row-0-col-0-from-cursorw)

And I found my issue is my image in blob (byte) will not load into my listView.

Then how can I solve my cameraIntent and save it to a specific folder then put it in database and load it in ListView. I really need your help and by examples. Thank You

What I was use is like this

```
 public void openCamera(int resultCode) {
    Inspection_JTR_Fragment_Foto_Tab.gallery = false;

    File image = new File(appFolderCheckandCreate(resultCode), "img" + getTimeStamp()
            + ".jpg");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
    id.co.bumisentosa.yantek.fragment_JTM.Inspection_JTM_Fragment_Foto_Tab.cameraImagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    i.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(i, resultCode);
}





private String appFolderCheckandCreate(int resultCode) {

    String appFolderPath = "";
    File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    switch (resultCode) {
        case 1:
            if (externalStorage.canWrite()) {
                appFolderPath = externalStorage.getAbsolutePath() + "/yantek-babel-android/jtr/Keseluruhan Tiang";
                File dir = new File(appFolderPath);

                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }

            } else {

            }
            break;

    }
    return appFolderPath;
}
```

And save it to database

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    final int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_upload) {
        // Upload data ke server

       imageArray = Inspection_JTM_Fragment_Foto_Tab.getimageArray();
        imageArray_2 = Inspection_JTM_Fragment_Foto_Tab.getimageArray_2();


        databaseHandler.saveTest(new ItemsDetails(


                imageArray,
                imageArray_2
                ));

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

my database

```
 public String saveTest(ItemsDetails details) {

    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        //  cv.put(KEY_ID, post.getId());
        //  cv.put(KEY_ID, "null");

        cv.put(COL_LOCATION_ID, details.getunitID());
        cv.put(COL_SECTION_ID, details.getjaringanID());
        cv.put(COL_INSPECTION_DATE, details.gettanggalInspeksi());
        cv.put(COL_INSPECTION_TYPE_ID, details.gettipeInspeksiID());

        cv.put(COL_PHOTO_ENTIRE_PATH, details.getimageArray());
        cv.put(COL_PHOTO_ISOLATOR_PATH, details.getimageArray_2());

        cv.put(COL_POLE_NO, details.getnoTiang());
        cv.put(COL_POLE_IRON, details.gettiangBesi());
        cv.put(COL_POLE_CONCRETE, details.gettiangBeton());
        cv.put(COL_POLE_WOOD, details.gettiangKayu());

        cv.put(COL_POLE_CONDITION_BROKEN, details.getkondisiTiangRetak());
        cv.put(COL_POLE_CONDITION_TILT, details.getkondisiTiangMiring());
        cv.put(COL_POLE_CONDITION_SHIFT, details.getkondisiTiangPindah());

        cv.put(COL_CROSS_ARM_TWIST, details.getcrossArmMelintir());
        cv.put(COL_CROSS_ARM_RUST, details.getcrossArmKarat());
        cv.put(COL_CROSS_ARM_TILT, details.getcrossArmMiring());

        cv.put(COL_ARM_TIE_REPAIR, details.getarmTiePerbaiki());
        cv.put(COL_ARM_TIE_RUST, details.getarmTieKarat());
        cv.put(COL_ARM_TIE_BRACE, details.getarmTiePasang());

        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_FULCRUM_R_LEAK, details.getisolatorTumpuRGompel());
        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_FULCRUM_R_BROKEN, details.getisolatorTumpuRPecah());
        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_FULCRUM_S_LEAK, details.getisolatorTumpuSGompel());
        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_FULCRUM_S_BROKEN, details.getisolatorTumpuSPecah());
        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_FULCRUM_T_LEAK, details.getisolatorTumpuTGompel());
        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_FULCRUM_T_BROKEN, details.getisolatorTumpuTPecah());

        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_PULL_R_LEAK, details.getisolatorTarikRGompel());
        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_PULL_R_BROKEN, details.getisolatorTarikRPecah());
        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_PULL_S_LEAK, details.getisolatorTarikSGompel());
        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_PULL_S_BROKEN, details.getisolatorTarikSPecah());
        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_PULL_T_LEAK, details.getisolatorTarikTGompel());
        cv.put(COL_ISOLATOR_PULL_T_BROKEN, details.getisolatorTarikTPecah());

        cv.put(COL_ARRESTER_R_BROKEN, details.getarresterRusakR());
        cv.put(COL_ARRESTER_S_BROKEN, details.getarresterRusakS());
        cv.put(COL_ARRESTER_T_BROKEN, details.getarresterRusakT());

        cv.put(COL_CONDUCTOR_R_BUYER, details.getkonduktorRBuyer());
        cv.put(COL_CONDUCTOR_R_LOOSE, details.getkonduktorRKendor());
        cv.put(COL_CONDUCTOR_S_BUYER, details.getkonduktorSBuyer());
        cv.put(COL_CONDUCTOR_S_LOOSE, details.getkonduktorSKendor());
        cv.put(COL_CONDUCTOR_T_BUYER, details.getkonduktorTBuyer());
        cv.put(COL_CONDUCTOR_T_LOOSE, details.getkonduktorTKendor());

        cv.put(COL_CONNECTOR_PG_R_35MM, details.getkonektorPGR35mm());
        cv.put(COL_CONNECTOR_PG_R_70MM, details.getkonektorPGR70mm());
        cv.put(COL_CONNECTOR_PG_R_150MM, details.getkonektorPGR150mm());

        cv.put(COL_CONNECTOR_PG_S_35MM, details.getkonektorPGS35mm());
        cv.put(COL_CONNECTOR_PG_S_70MM, details.getkonektorPGS70mm());
        cv.put(COL_CONNECTOR_PG_S_150MM, details.getkonektorPGS150mm());

        cv.put(COL_CONNECTOR_PG_T_35MM, details.getkonektorPGT35mm());
        cv.put(COL_CONNECTOR_PG_T_70MM, details.getkonektorPGT70mm());
        cv.put(COL_CONNECTOR_PG_T_150MM, details.getkonektorPGT150mm());

        cv.put(COL_BENDING_WIRE_R, details.getbendingWireR());
        cv.put(COL_BENDING_WIRE_S, details.getbendingWireS());
        cv.put(COL_BENDING_WIRE_T, details.getbendingWireT());

        cv.put(COL_ULTRASONIC_R, details.getultrasonicR());
        cv.put(COL_ULTRASONIC_S, details.getultrasonicS());
        cv.put(COL_ULTRASONIC_T, details.getultrasonicT());

        cv.put(COL_GSW_EXIST, details.getgswAda());
        cv.put(COL_GSW_NOT_EXIST, details.getgswTidakAda());

        cv.put(COL_TREE_EXIST, details.getpohonAda());
        cv.put(COL_TREE_NOT_EXIST, details.getpohonTidakAda());

        cv.put(COL_LONGITUDE, details.getlongitude());
        cv.put(COL_LATITUDE, details.getlatitude());

        cv.put(COL_SUGGESTION, details.getSaran());
        cv.put(COL_DESCR, details.getketerangan());


        db.insert(INSPECTIONS_MV_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return getNewTestID();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Then how can I solve my cameraIntent and save it to a specific folder
>   then put it in database and load it in ListView. I really need your
>   help and by examples.

In short you can't. Although you can store the image in the database you cannot retrieve it from the database because it is too large to fit into a CursorWindow which has a limitation of 2MB (2097152).

The image itself is around 1432389 bytes but the CursorWindow only has 750700 bytes. So as 1432389 is greater than 750700 image (blob) it can't be extracted.

You can get around the issue if you :-

```
save it to a specific folder, then
save the path (or part of the path) in the database rather than the image, and then
extract the path and then get the image via the path when loading the ListView.
```