# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow

Tags: java, android, sqlite, illegalstateexception

I need to fetch all data from a table,I used the following code to do the same in sqlite dbhelper class:

```
public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + PRODUCT_DETAILS_TABLE, null);
        return res;
    }
```

Now i'm fetching data using curser in my activity in the following way:

```
  public HashMap<String, ArrayList<CartModal>> getDatas() {

            map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<CartModal>>();
            stored_data = new ArrayList<CartModal>();
            Cursor cartdb = dbHelper.getData();
            if (cartdb != null && cartdb.getCount() > 0) {
                if (cartdb.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String mloggedinuser = cartdb.getString(0);
                        String mname = cartdb.getString(1);
                        String email = cartdb.getString(2);
                        String mobile = cartdb.getString(3);
                        String about = cartdb.getString(4);
                        String pid = cartdb.getString(5);
                        String refnum = cartdb.getString(6);
                        String size = cartdb.getString(7);
                        String weight = cartdb.getString(8);
                        String price = cartdb.getString(9);
                        String catid = cartdb.getString(10);
                        String image = cartdb.getString(11);

                        CartModal cartarray = new CartModal(mloggedinuser, mname, email, mobile, about, pid, refnum, size, weight, price, catid, image);
                        stored_data.add(cartarray);
                        keys = mname;
                        map.put(mname, stored_data);
                    } while (cartdb.moveToPosition(stored_data.size()));
                    cartdb.close();
                }
            }
            return map;
        }
```

When i run the above program i'm getting error as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: sdetech.io.brouchuretabproject, PID: 2434
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                      at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                      at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
                      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                      at sdetech.io.brouchuretabproject.Fragments.Cart.getDatas(Cart.java:58)
                      at sdetech.io.brouchuretabproject.Fragments.Cart.onCreateView(Cart.java:42)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:541)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I've gone through many solutions in stackoverflow ([android java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432556/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-couldnt-read-row-0-col-0-from-cursorw) ),but none helped me to solve this issue.
Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: if you want to show your data on yhe `ListView` then remove `getDatas` method and just use `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: I'm not able to find anything logically wrong with the code, may be you can try debugging your code manually by putting breakpoints and see where things are going wrong.

Comment: you have only one instance of `stored_data` and you are adding new data to that instance again and again

Comment: @pskink I need the data in an arraylist

Comment: Hardik Modha I'm getting error at : String mloggedinuser = cartdb.getString(0);

Comment: you have your data in the `Cursor` why do you need arraylist?

Comment: i want the arraylist to be used in the expandable listview. I'm getting error at : String mloggedinuser = cartdb.getString(0);

Comment: so use `android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`, no need to read the whole `Cursor`

Comment: @pskink Can you suggest me where am i going wrong in the above method?

Comment: i already did: *"you have only one instance of stored_data and you are adding new data to that instance again and again"*, but honestly you are wrong because you are not using `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`

Comment: @pskink Can u show me how to use SimpleCursorTreeAdapter in the above code?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.java, notice `getChildrenCursor` method

Comment: Can anyone suggest me a solution for this issue?

Comment: ok [here](http://pastebin.com/94hD4ciD) you have the simplest working code

Answer (score 0):

I was doing everything right.but the problem was,i was saving an image in db as base64 ecoded string.while fetching that data it shows illegal exception.when i removed that image it works pefectly.
If anyone know how to save base64 encoded image as string in sqlite,please reply below.

Thankyou