# Android SQLite Error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, sqlite

When I compose the 2MB Mail and sent to my same email id. Then I am trying to reply same mail[2MB]. It was sending. When open the reply mail I am getting the following error.

> Error : "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0
>   from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialised correctly
>   before accessing data from it."

Error is coming in this line:

```
cursor.getString(0);
```

Comment: 2MB is too big. Don't store stuff that big in a database. Save it to the file system instead, and store the path(s) in the db. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21432556

Answer (score 0):

Consider first getting column index and then attempting to read the value. Since you didn't post your code, I can only suggest the following:

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(0));
```

For example, your code could look something like this:

```
String query = "some_query_here";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      String result  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(0));
      cursor.moveToNext();
   }
   cursor.close();
}
```

Perhaps, you made a mistake in initializing the `Cursor` object. Consider rechecking your code.

Comment: Hi Serj, I have tried your code. its coming into if block and while block . count is 1. but still it throwing the Error : Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 2 columns."java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialised correctly before accessing data from it."

Answer (score 0):

If your `Cursor` returned any rows then it would contain **at least 1 column with index 0**, so there would be no error.
But it seems that **it is empty** (no rows).
All you need to check for the existence of any row is `moveToFirst()` which returns `true` if there exists a 1st row (so any row):

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String columnvalue = cursor.getString(0);  
} else {
    // write your code here
}
```

Comment: Hi Forpas,  Thanks for the reply. I have checked the cursor count. count is 1. then i have checked the cursor.moveToFirst(). it was true. Then its enter into the block. but am facing same the  Error : "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialised correctly before accessing data from it."

Comment: Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

look like your row is having more than 2MB data size so cursor is throwing IllegalStateException.