# How to fix in sqLite: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin, android-sqlite

I'm tying to get the data from sqLite from this table

```
        db.execSQL("create table cabling(Code text, note text, lat text, lng text, teamColor text, jobType text, image1 text, image2 text, image3 text, image4 text, image5 text, cable text, assawer text, ankor text, mwaser text, building_no text)")
```

the return function is

```
@SuppressLint("Recycle")
override fun returnCabling(db: SQLiteDatabase): ArrayList<CablingData> {
    val cur = db.rawQuery("select * from cabling", arrayOf())

    val cabling = ArrayList<CablingData>()
    cur.moveToFirst()

    while (!cur.isAfterLast) {
        cabling.add(
            CablingData(
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Code")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("note")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("lat")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("lng")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("teamColor")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("jobType")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("image1")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("image2")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("image3")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("image4")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("image5")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("cable")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("assawer")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("ankor")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("mwaser")),
                cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("building_no"))
            )
        )

        AppLogger.log("cabling", cabling.toString())
        cur.moveToNext()
    }
    cur.close()
    return cabling
}
```

it's return

> Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

but when I use this

```
val cur2 = db.rawQuery("select Code, note, lat, lng from cabling", arrayOf())
    cur2.moveToFirst()
    while (!cur2.isAfterLast) {
        AppLogger.log("testststs", cur2.getString(cur2.getColumnIndex("Code")))

        cur2.moveToNext()

    }
```

it's work **BUT if I write all of the element in select statement it is gonna crash**

> select Code, note, lat, lng, teamColor, jobType, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, cable, assawer, ankor, mwaser, building_no from cabling

this statement above won't work

thank you all for helping

**<3**

Comment: First uninstall the app from the device and rerun.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working

Comment: Execute that last while loop once for each of the columns to find which column(s) cause the problem.

Comment: All those "image" columns smell like binary large data. Android sqlite CursorWinfow only supports rows of up to 2 megabytes.

Comment: how to fix the size issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21432556